# How can we identify a buffer belongs to user space or kernel space from a kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am writing a driver in which a few functions are called either by a user-space dev node or from another MFD device driver. I need to identify whether the buffer belongs to user space or kernel space, to decide if I should use a `copy_to_user()` vs `memcpy()`.

Comment: You could pass a flag parameter to indicate whether the pointer is kernel space or user space. Or you could pass both a user space pointer and a kernel space parameter with one of them set to NULL, and test which one is valid. That would have the advantage of being able to tag the user space pointer with `__user` for sparse analysis.

Comment: Look, for example, at how  `bitmap_parselist_user()` is implemented https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/bitmap.c#L638